# Wagtail Images Suddenly Not Rendering on Front End

Tags: django, image, wagtail, html-rendering

I have just encountered an odd problem I'm trying to debug but cannot figure out what is wrong.

I have a wagtail site with images that were all working. At one point I refreshed the browser, and the images suddenly all disappeared from every page.

- wagtailimages_tags is there
- static is all loaded
- the images are all in the correct media directory as specified and have been uploaded through the CMS
- if i inspect element, the image is in fact coming through in the code perfectly.

[image]

But the site itself just does not show the image. I have checked the CSS and nothing has changed there and it is not hiding the image somehow.

My last resort - I actually started the project over completely in a new environment and added each application one by one to see if I could solve the issue ... nope. No images on the new install from scratch either!

No idea why all the images would suddenly just fail to appear in browser. Just seems super strange to me.

Any ideas on debugging appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The path to one of the js files had an extra /js in it and was not loading the file the page needed. The console showed and error and said it could not find /img.url - weird but the file in question where the error was found was the js file with the incorrect path.

This mistake caused every path to load perfectly but strategically blocked a few things globally that a little extra reading of the console would have helped me figure out sooner.

Fixed the .js file path and now all is good.